# Ph-schematron library not found on classpath?

Tags: java, spring, hl7-fhir

i receved the error but i have included the resource in java spring project

```
14:37:17.010 [main] INFO ca.uhn.fhir.util.VersionUtil -- HAPI FHIR version 6.4.3 - Rev cfc9af8148
14:37:17.029 [main] INFO ca.uhn.fhir.context.FhirContext -- Creating new FHIR context for FHIR version [R4]
14:37:17.034 [main] INFO ca.uhn.fhir.validation.FhirValidator -- Ph-schematron library not found on classpath, will not attempt to perform schematron validation
14:37:17.285 [main] WARN ca.uhn.fhir.validation.SchemaBaseValidator -- Jaxp 1.5 Support not found.
```

dependencies add for the pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi.fhir</groupId>
            <artifactId>hapi-fhir-validation-resourcesr4</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.helger.schematron</groupId>
            <artifactId>ph-schematron-validator</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
```